# SQL слияние двух подзапросов

Tags: sql

Имеется запрос:

```
select detail_table.TABLE_NAME DETAIL_TABLE_NAME,
 detail_table.column_name DETAIL_COLUMN,
 ind_column.INDEX_NAME
 from
 user_constraints constraint_info
 left join user_cons_columns detail_table on constraint_info.CONSTRAINT_NAME = detail_table.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 left join USER_IND_COLUMNS ind_column on ind_column.TABLE_NAME = detail_table.TABLE_NAME and ind_column.COLUMN_NAME = detail_table.COLUMN_NAME
 where constraint_info.constraint_type = 'R' and ind_column.INDEX_NAME is null
 order by detail_table.TABLE_NAME;
```

который возвращает таблицу вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется, чтобы поле INDEX_NAME имело вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делал различные подзапросы с использованием CONCAT, CONCAT_WS, но требуемого результата так и не получил( Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: detail_table.TABLE_NAME + '.' + detail_table.column_name as INDEX_NAME

Comment: Обычная конкатенация. Судя по именам таблиц, это Oracle? тогда `detail_table.table_name || '.' || detail_table.column_name AS index_name`

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло. Я новичок на сайте, не могу разобраться как проголосовать за какой-либо ответ(

Comment: stafford831 - если автор комментария оформит ответ именно как "ответ" (сейчас это - комментарий), Вы сможете на него проголосовать.